# Changing website content dynamically depending on MySQL database value

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to change my website dynamically based on a value. I retrive data from my MySQL database and want the change to be as close to real-time as possible. I have some code that does what I want to some extent, but the updating of the values seem to fail, at first it works and then after a few calls it seems to just switch at random between the two values.

I have three php pages, one that retrives a value from the database (database.php) and two that generate a response based on the database value(response1.php and response2.php). I do not think that these pages are part of the problem, since I have checked that they return values and they return what I want. The second part of the project (and where it probably fails) is my main html page (below). I am unsure if I have chosen the best technique to solve my problem or if there is a better way to do it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var databaseanswer, xmlhttp;

        function databasecheck() {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "database.php", true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    databaseanswer = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("database").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function response() {
            if (databaseanswer == "No Tag") {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "response1.php", true);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
            else {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "response2.php", true);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }

        setInterval(databasecheck, 1800);
        setInterval(response, 2000);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> this is a test site </p>
    <p> response from server: </p>
    <div id="response">
    </div>
    <p> answer from database: </p>
    <div id="database">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Okay, so this is my edited code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function database(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.open("GET","responsedatabase.php",false);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("database").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
      }
  xmlhttp.send();
}

setInterval(database,1000);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>answer from database: </p><div id="database"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should look into doing this with `jQuery's` `AJAX` functionality: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: `if (databaseanswer == "No Tag") {` makes no sense, or whatsoever

Comment: basically "No Tag" is the default value in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending multiple asynchronous requests and the requests are not serialized. Keep in mind that you have no control over the response times of the requests. Also, as the time goes by, the amount of time between the `response` and the `databasecheck` invocations keeps increasing. For ex. initially, the `databasecheck` will be executed after 1.8 seconds and the `response` will be executed after 2 seconds; the difference is 200 ms. The second time, `databasecheck` will be executed after 3.6 seconds and the `response` will be executed after 4 seconds; the difference is 400 ms.

Apart from that, the response times of the requests are not under your controls. It is not necessary that the first request you make will necessarily be the first one to be finished. That is, even if you serialize the calls to `databasecheck` and `response` functions, if you don't serialize the XHR calls, you will be getting visibly random results. That is, suppose that `databasecheck` returned `x` and you sent a request for `response1.php`; while it is still in progress, suppose a second request for `databasecheck` returned `y` and another request for `response2.php` was initiated. Now depending on the order in which the requests for `response1.php` and `response2.php` were finished, you might see a correct or an incorrect result. And, while that is happening, another request for the `database.php` might be finished and you will once again be seeing some different result. That is the cause for apparent randomness in results.

What you need to do is serialize the calls to `databasecheck` and the `response` functions. That is, initiate the call to `response` only after the request for `database.php` is finished. Now, you need to make sure that the there is no race-condition between the requests as well.  That is a little cumbersome and you might lost the real-time behavior.

A better way is to combine the results of the calls to `database.php` and the calls to either `response1.php` and `response2.php`. That is, move the logic to the server-side. Put the code in `response1.php` and `response2.php` in functions that return values. Suppose these to functions are named `response1` and `response2`. In your `database.php`. call either of these functions based on the database-value. Put the results in an associative array, along with the database value and return the response as a JSON formatted string. This way, you will make one less request and there are no synchronization problems.

**After Update**

You need to do the following in your updated code:

```
var requestInProgress = false;
function database() {
    if(requestInProgress) {
        return;
    }
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("GET","responsedatabase.php",false);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            requestInProgress = false;
            if(xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("database").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    requestInProgress = true; 
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

You could also probably reduce the duration in the `setInterval` to make sure that there is never much delay between the ending of the previous request and the beginning of a new request.

Comment: Okay, so I have combined my response1.php and response2.php into my database.php (thus making the choice of response in that file). And then I do a XMLHttpRequest for database.php, but this gives me the same synchronisation problems.

Comment: Post your new JS code. There shouldn't be any more race-conditions as there should be only one function call and only one request. Also, do not make a new request while a previous request is in progress.

Comment: I have added the edited code to my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, this seems to work a lot better, but it is far from happening in realtime - is there anything I can do to improve this, or am I limited by using this technique? (Should I look into doing another way? And do you have any suggestions for how).

Comment: Actually, there still seems to be some problems with wrong values (it will still output "No Tag", even if that is not the value in the database. I am thinking it might be PHP caching or something like that? I have added - header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); to the start of my php document (but that does not work).

Comment: Did you resolve the race-condition between the requests? Can you post your PHP code? I don't need to see the whole function content, just see what's happening. By the way, if your database is updated more frequently than the speed with which the requests can be finished, you _will_ have discrepancy between the content in the database and what you see on the page. Real-time behavior is not an exact thing with Ajax requests; it is just a simulation of an apparent real-time behavior.

Comment: So basically this just happend. I went for lunch, and I met a couple of older students who were also working on getting contact with a database - and they have had the same problems as me. It turns out that it was my webhost caching pages, so I added a .htaccess file with the following code: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) - [L,E=Cache-Control:no-cache] 
</IfModule> and now it works! Thanks for the help, I greatly appreciate it! :-)